# WebService Best Performance: Multiple calls with few data or little calls with huge data

Tags: php, performance, web-services, memory, soap

I have to consume a WebService for getting products from one provider in my webpage written in PHP.

I have two options:

1. There are 1 operation for getting the data of ALL products, I can call this operation four times (one per language I need) and parse the data to obtain the data related to the products I want; the problem is that PHP runs out of memory...and I need to notably increase the memory_limit in this script.
2. I can call 1 operation for getting one product data...then if I need to fetch 2500 products, I would make 2500 calls * 4 (for each language), resulting in 10.000 calls...at least it would be no memory problems.

Which options is better?

Edit: This operation is intended to be executed only one time per year.

Comment: I think  the second option is good, even though the requests are more here but they are done in some timely fashion(not all at a time, which would induce lot of performance issues).

Comment: Well, it depends on you and your system. But I think your service provider won't like the 10 000 calls, I'm pretty sure 4 big calls are better for him. You should maybe check it (If not already done) before wondering about memory